# Proving that if $C$ is a prefix code then it is uniquely decipherable?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, coding-theory

I'm reading James Anderson's *Automata Theory with Modern Applications. Here:*

> [image]
>
> [image]

And I tried to prove the following theorem (for prefix codes).

> [image]

I tried in the following way: Suppose $C$ is a prefix code which is not uniquely decipherable, that is there is a string $u \in C$ with two different expressions $u=ab=cd$. But $u=vw$ and hence $vw=ab=cd$ where $w= \lambda$ and $\lambda$ is the empty word, therefore $v=a=c$ and $\lambda=b=d$ which contradicts your hypothesis that $u$ is not uniquely decipherable.

Is this correct? I am confused because I paired $v=a=c$ and $\lambda=b=d$ and I'm not sure if that is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Let $1$ be the empty word. First of all, one needs to discard the case $C = \{1\}$ for the result to be correct. Indeed, if $C = \{1\}$, then $C$ is a prefix code, but $C^*$ is not a free monoid.

Let now $C$ be a nonempty prefix code such that $C \not= \{1\}$. Then $C$ does not contain $1$, since $1$ is a prefix of every word. Let $w$ be a word of minimal length having two $C$-factorizations
$$
w = c_1 \dotsm c_n = c'_1 \dotsm c'_m
$$
Both $c_1$ and $c'_1$ are nonempty words and since $w$ has minimal length, $c_1 ≠ c'_1$. Thus either $c_1$ is a prefix of $c'_1$, or the other way around. Contradiction.

Comment: Why not use the OP's notation for empty string ($\lambda$)? (+1 for the comment on $\lambda \notin C$.)

Comment: @copper-hat The notation $\lambda$ (or $\epsilon$) for the empty word was introduced by computer scientists because they often work with the binary alphabet $\{0, 1\}$. But otherwise, especially on a mathematical forum, it is more natural to stick with the standard notation of the identity of a monoid (or a group), which is $1$.

Comment: Perhaps, but I have **never** seen the group identity (why not $e$?) used in this context.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to do an inductive proof on the number of code symbols in two words.

Suppose $C$ is a prefix code for $S$.

I use $|s|$ for the length (in terms of $\Sigma$) of $s$.

Choose $s \in S$ and write $s=c_1 t_1 = c_2 t_2$ where $c_k \in C$ and $t_k \in C^*$.
Suppose $|c_1| \le |c_2|$ and write $s= c_1 w t_1'$, where $|w| = |c_2|-|c_1|$ and $t_1 = w t_1'$. Then $c_1w = c_2$ and hence $c_1 = c_2$ and $w = \lambda$.
Now repeat with $t_1, t_2$.

Comment: What is the meaning of $|c_1| \leq |c_2|$? Until now I didn't see this notation in the book. Is it string length?

Comment: Yes, the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

If $ab=cd$, and $a≠c$, then one of $a$ and $c$ is shorter and one is longer. The shorter is a prefix of the longer, therefore the code is not a prefix code.

Comment: In this case, we're assuming $C$ is a prefix code and the elements of $C$ are not uniquely decipherable and obtaining a contradiction to our assumption that $C$ is a prefix code, right?

Comment: That seems a little bit roundabout to me, but if you're happy with it so am I.